# Something adds a parameter to every URL inside every HTML file that is requested

Tags: html, http, nginx, hyperlink, cdn

We run a website with nginx and going through a CDN.

The problem we have is we've noticed that every URL that is inside every webpage is generated with a parameter, quite like ?123456 at the end of the URL.

This parameter is always the same, and is there i.e. for images, for javascript, or for CSS, as with . My bet is that it has to do with some server level rewrite, but it looks extremely weird that the whole html files are somehow parsed in between our code and the user so that this useless parameter is added.

Has any of this ever happened to you?

Comment: This sounds like asset versioning – protecting static assets like CSS and JS from outdated cache copies. Many webmasters add a fake query (like ?123456) to the end of the link so that CDN thinks "this is version 123456". Of course, without more details it's impossible to say what's wrong, but this is the first guess

Comment: The strange thing is that in our case we are the creators of the webpage, and the fake part (?123456) isn't added anywhere in our code. So the only remaining possibility is that the server somehow does it when serving the code. We haven't seen anything weird on the nginx basic config, but the machine isn't ours.

Comment: What CDN are you using? Possible locations where this is configured: CDN settings and/or your source code. If you see these links inside of your HTML contents – I would say nginx config is out of suspicion.